# How to copy file from network path to local appdata for each remote PC

Tags: powershell

So i have a file with PC's and their respective users in a CSV called `test.csv`; the file looks like this:

> ```
> Computer, User
> pcname1, john.doe
> pcname2, jane.doe
> ```

My script looks like this

```
$list = Import-Csv -Path C:\temp\test.csv

ForEach ($Computer in $list) {


Copy-Item -Path \\domain.local\SYSVOL\domain.local\scripts\copyfile.txt -Destination \\$list.Computer\C$\Users\$list.User\AppData\Local\filedepot\

}
```

The `Copy-Item` works if i manually enter the PC name and username in the variables.

But as soon as i use the `$list`. it doesn't work..

If i use `echo` it does show me the correct data so it does pick up the right info..

Not sure why this doesn't work, any help is appreciated

Comment: that's because you're using the imported list as the variable. You need to use your `$Computer` variable instead of `$list.Computer`.

Comment: if your csv has a column named "Computer", you would have to iterate through it like so in your foreach loop: `foreach($Computer in $List.Computer){…`

Comment: so to summarize it. When you iterate through each computer in `$Computer.List`, each computer name will get assigned to `$Computer` one at a time and will execute your expressions of `copy-item`. So foreach `$computer` in `$list.computer` do the following (this is how its represented).

Comment: ```-Destination \\$($list.Computer)\C$\Users\$($list.User)\AppData\Local\filedepot\``` could work, using [Subexpression operator `$( )`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7#subexpression-operator--) twice.

Comment: You should put "" quotes around the path, in case there's a space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use objects, no need to lookup the list twice

```
$list = Import-Csv -Path C:\temp\test.csv

Foreach($l in $list){

$computer = $l.Computer
$user = $l.User

$sourcepath = "\\domain.local\SYSVOL\domain.local\scripts\copyfile.txt"
$destinationpath = "\\$computer\C$\Users\$user\AppData\Local\filedepot"

If(Test-Path -Path $destinationpath){
    Copy-Item -Path $sourcepath -Destination $destinationpath -Force
}Else{
    Write-Host "Destination path not found - $destinationpath" -ForegroundColor Red
}

}
```